# Should I focus on skills or achievements when submitting resumes to an unrelated field?

Tags: career-switch, developer

I am currently a entry-level developer in the healthcare industry, but would prefer to step out of a technical role and into more of an analyst role.

Most of my achievements are technical/software related and have no relevance to any requirements that an analyst job listing might show.

**On a resume, would it be more beneficial to highlight skills that might translate, or quantifiable achievements that I've made on the (unrelated) job?**

Comment: If you are currently entry level, your resume should have room for both.

Answer (score 3):

Both.

There's no reason you have to focus on one or the other - the volume of your work, AND the skill with which you can assist others at your new position, are both valuable.

I would, however, label them appropriately.  I would list your accomplishments from your previous job under the listing of that job, to show what you accomplished while working there, and list your relevant job skills separately under a "Job Skills" heading.